# codeigniter JSON

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, codeigniter

Hello im using codeigniter and then i echo out my output from the database in my controller and then in my view file i do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.getJSON('ajax/forumThreads', function(data) {          
alert(data.overskrift);
});

</script>
```

but it dont show anything :S

my model file

```
function forumList()
{
    $this->db->select('overskrift', 'indhold', 'brugernavn', 'dato');
    $this->db->order_by('id', 'desc');
    $forum_list = $this->db->get('forum_traad');

    if($forum_list->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $forum_list->result();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

my controller

```
function forumThreads() {

    $this->load->model('ajax_model');
    $data['forum_list'] = $this->ajax_model->forumList();

    if ($data['forum_list'] === true)
    {
        echo json_encode($data['forum_list']);
        $this->load->view('includes/footer', $data); 
    } else {
        return  false;
    }


}
```

Comment: a good way to test for me has been to just try and visit the controller function "in the wild" just typing it in the browser and see what the output is, just so you know you are getting the output you expect.

Comment: Remove `$this->load->view('includes/footer', $data);` after the `json_encode`.  JSON data cannot have anything before or after it.

Answer (score 3):

`$forum_list->result()` returns an array of results.

If you only want 1 row, use `$forum_list->row()`, otherwise in the javascript, you'll need to loop through all the rows.

```
$.each(data, function(i,v){
  alert(v.overskrift);
});
```

EDIT: When outputting JSON, do not print anything before or after.  You need to remove `$this->load->view('includes/footer', $data);` after the `json_encode`.  Also, controllers don't return anything.

EDIT 2: Replace `if ($data['forum_list'] === true)` with `if ($data['forum_list'] !== false)`.  The `===` compares type, and an array is not a boolean.

Comment: okay i have done all that you said and it output something if i browse to the controller, but it alert: undefined :S

Comment: @ole: What does the controller output?

Answer (score 0):

Model:

```
function forumList()
{
    $this->db->select('overskrift', 'indhold', 'brugernavn', 'dato');
    $this->db->order_by('id', 'desc');
    $forum_list = $this->db->get('forum_traad');

    if($forum_list->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $forum_list->result_array();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
function forumThreads() {

    $this->load->model('ajax_model');
    $data['forum_list'] = $this->ajax_model->forumList();

    if ($data['forum_list'] !== false) {
        echo json_encode($data['forum_list']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//works only with php 5.3
echo json_encode($data['forum_list'], JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```